# Checking the id of an element jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 3 different objects with 3 different id's that I'd i'm passing to a function. I'd like to check which id is being sent down to the function and then alert something different for each id. I have this code but it doesn't work and i'm not sure if it's even right at all or possible to do it this way. With the $(this), i was trying to get the element that I am currently dragging and send it down to the checkForID function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#option1').draggable();
 $('#option2').draggable();
 $('#option3').draggable();

 checkforID($(this));

 });

 function checkforID(value)
{
  if(value == $('#option1')
  alert('You've picked option1');
  else  if(value == $('#option2')
  alert('You've picked option2');
  else  if(value == $('#option3')
  alert('You've picked option3');

}
```

Comment: Can you please add a complete code, especially in which function contect you have used `checkforID($(this))`. Folks are getting confused with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given any context for where you're calling `checkforID`, but I'm going to assume it somewhere where `this` refers to a DOM element, such as within a jQuery event handler.

If you're passing in a jQuery object (as you appear to be):

```
var id = value.attr("id");
```

...which will give you the `id` of the first element in the set (jQuery objects are sets; in your quoted code, the set will have just one element).

If you just pass in an element:

```
var id = value.id;
```

---

Re your comment:

> I was actually trying to pass down the id of the element that i am currently dragging. Will $(this) not work?

`this` is correct, it's the element being dragged (no need to wrap it in a jQuery object unless you want to), provided the code is within any of the event handlers for a draggable, such as `start`, `stop`, or `drag`. Here's an example (note the event handlers): [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/xojipeqa/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Drag example</title>
  <style>
    .draggable {
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: #aaa;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="display">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="d1" class="draggable"></div>
  <div id="d2" class="draggable"></div>
  <div id="d3" class="draggable"></div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var display = $("#display");
      $(".draggable").draggable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
          display.html("You're dragging " + this.id);
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
          display.html("You stopped dragging");
        }
      })
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But what would be passed for `$(this)`? The this keyword will have a value depends on the scope

Comment: @Murali: Yeah, hit refresh, I was just flagging that up. (And no, it doesn't depend on scope; it depends on how the code containing `this` was called.)

Comment: I was actually trying to pass down the id of the element that i am currently dragging. Will $(this) not work? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: @John: `this` is fine if it's in the right place, see the update, I've done a `draggable` example.

Answer (score 1):

In your code **checkforID($(this))**, the `$(this)` will send the global `window` object to the function.

Please send the appropriate object

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
 function checkforID(value)
{
  var id = $(value).attr('id');
  if(id == '#option1')
  alert("You've picked option1");
  else  if(id == '#option2')
  alert("You've picked option2");
  else  if(id == '#option3')
  alert("You've picked option3");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you're looking for **[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)**:

```
function checkforID(value) {
  if(value.is('#option1')) alert("You've picked option1");
  else if(value.is('#option2')) alert("You've picked option2");
  else if(value.is('#option3')) alert("You've picked option3");
}
```